# Is the fixed locus of a group action always a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Suppose G is an algebraic group with an action G×X→X on a scheme. Does the fixed locus (the set of points x∈X fixed by all of G) have a scheme structure? You can obviously define the functor Fix(T)={t∈X(T)|t is fixed by every element of G(T)}. Is this functor always representable?

(This question was "broken off" of [a compound question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3124/do-orbits-and-stable-loci-of-group-actions-have-natural-scheme-structures) after Scott Carnahan answered the other part so wonderfully that I had to accept his answer.)

Comment: As Scott points out below, Anton's definition does not give a functor.  Perhaps the following is a better definition.  Let Stab be the stabilizer group scheme over X (the fiber product of the action map GxX --> XxX with the diagonal).  Let Fix be the subsheaf of points of X where Stab --> G is an isomorphism.  (In Scott's example of Gm acting on A<sup>n</sup> this gives the origin, as it should.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The question gives the "wrong" definition of Fix(T), hence the resulting confusion.

A more natural definition of the subfunctor X^G of "G-fixed points in X" is
(X^G)(T) = {x in X(T) | G_T-action on X_T fixes x}
               = {x in X(T) | G(T')-action on X(T') fixes x for *all* T-schemes T'}.
(Of course, can just as well restriction to affine T and T' for "practical" purposes.)

By way of analogy with more classical situations, if the base is a field k then a moment's reflection with the case of finite k shows that
{x in X(k) | G(k) fixes x}
is the "wrong" notion of (X^G)(k), whereas
{x in X(k) | G-action on X fixes x}
is a "better" notion, and is what the above definition of (X^G)(k) says.

From this point of view, if (for simplicity of notation) the base scheme is an affine Spec(k) for a commutative ring k then the "scheme of G-fixed points" exists whenever G is affine and X is separated provided that k[G] is k-free (or becomes so after faithfully flat extension on k).  So this works when k is a field, or any k if G is a k-torus (or "of multiplicative type").  See Proposition A.8.10(1) in the book [Pseudo-reductive groups](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/predfinal.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope you don't mind I've edited your question to include a link to a pdf of the book.

Comment: By the way, you can type math between dollar signs to get nice LaTeX-like output. For example, typing `\$x\in X^G(T)\$` will produce $x\in X^G(T)$.

Answer (score 6):

Let F be the field with two elements, and let G = **G**<sub>m,F</sub>.  Let X = A<sup>n</sup>, affine space of dimension n (at least 1), with G acting by dilations.  Then G(F) is trivial, so Fix(F) = X(F), which has elements other than the origin.  Fix(**F**<sub>4</sub>) is the origin, but it should contain all the **F**<sub>4</sub>-points that factor through the canonical map to Spec F.  Fix is therefore not representable.

Comment: Yikes! I thought for sure the answer would be yes. It looks like the problem is basically that Fix is not a sheaf. Do you know if it becomes representable if you take the (fppf) sheafification?

Comment: I think the problem is that Fix isn't even a functor.  It doesn't seem to respect morphisms.

Comment: Double Yikes  !