# Under what hypotheses are schematic fixed points of a flat deformation themselves flat?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, torus-action, flatness

This is something of a follow-up question to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43255/); I hope people won't think this is a duplicate.  At least in my head, it seems like a distinct enough question to merit a fresh start.

All my schemes will be finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$.  Let $X\to S$ be a flat family of affine schemes over smooth affine base.  Let's say for now that each fiber and the whole family have rational singularities, and thus are Cohen-Macaulay.  Assume, furthermore, that $X$ has an action of the group scheme $T=(\mathbb{G}_m)_S$; this is the same data as a grading on $k[X]$ such that $k[S]$ has degree 0.

Now, we can take the schematic fixed points $X^T$ of this family, which is a subscheme of $X$ whose points over any ring are invariant points of $X$. Concretely, this is the vanishing set of the ideal generated by all functions of non-zero degree.

> Must the morphism $X^T\to S$ be flat?  If not, are there stricter hypotheses than I gave above which would assure it is?

For example, consider the family $$X=\mathrm{Spec}[x,y,z,a_0,\dots, a_{n-1}]/(xy=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0)$$ where $S=\mathrm{Spec}[a_0,\dots, a_{n-1}]$  with $x$ having degree 1, $y$ degree $-1$ and $z,a_i$ having degree 0.  In this case $$X^T=\mathrm{Spec}[z,a_0,\dots, a_{n-1}]/(z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0=0),$$ which is, of course, flat over $S$, even though the number of closed points in a fiber (the number of roots of $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$) varies from $n$ to $1$.

Comment: This is false for general group actions.  Think of the additive group acting on P^1 x C with x sending (z,t) to (z + tx, t); the dimension of the fixed points at t = 0 jumps.  I haven't been able come up with an example like this for torus actions, so I'm starting to believe it.

Comment: Another thought: maybe one can reduce to the case of a finite group, thinking of a (char zero) torus as a limit of its finite subgroups.

Comment: The behavior of reductive groups is quite different that of unipotent ones, so the counterexample doesn't worry me so much.  After all, the degree 0 part of the ring has to vary flatly, and that's the coordinate ring of the categorical quotient, so nothing too horrible can happen.

Comment: Dear David: Good thought. Consider noetherian scheme $S$ and flat $S$-scheme $X$ of f. type equipped with action by $S$-torus $T$.  Then $X^T$ exists as closed subscheme of $X$, & formation commutes with  base change. To check flatness, WLOG $S$ is local. Pick prime $\ell$ invertible on $S$, and observe that the collection of finite etale $S$-subgroups $G_n=T[\ell^n]$ is relatively sch. dense in $T$. Thus, $X^T = X^{G_n}$ for large $n$ by noetherianness. By finite etale base change on $S$, $G_n$ constant. So problem reduces to analogue for action by finite gp of order invertible on $S$. Hmm...

Comment: Note also that by the "valuative criterion" for flatness, to handle the case when (noetherian) $S$ is reduced it suffices to handle the case when $S$ is the spectrum of a dvr. 

Comment: There's an old theorem of Iversen that, for any field $k$, for a *smooth* (& separated) $k$-scheme $X$ and a $k$-torus $T$, the fixed scheme $X^T$ is smooth.  I'd wager that one could replace "smooth" with "Cohen-Macaulay" in this statement -- though the proof would have to be somewhat different from Iversen's.  Anyone know a counterexample?  (Since in your motivating situation, I think you know that the dimension of fibers of $X^T\to S$ is constant, knowing $X^T$ is C-M gives flatness over a smooth base $S$.)

Comment: This is false for finite groups, though. Consider two copies of the affine line glued at the origin, with an action of a cyclic group of order 2 switching the two copies, mapping to the affine line.

Comment: Dear Angelo: Good point. So perhaps one should "remember" a shadow of connectedness of tori in the form that the resulting finite group action preserves generic points in fibers...though maybe there's another obstruction to flatness lurking around. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $\mathbb G_{\rm m}$ act on $\mathbb A^2$ by $t\cdot(x,y) = (tx,t^{-1}y)$, and let $f\colon \mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^1$ be defined by $f(x,y) = xy$.

I am positive that when $X$ is smooth over $Y$, the fixed point scheme is also smooth; but I doubt that one can say much more, in general.

[Edit] Here is a variant. Let  $\mathbb G_{\rm m}$ act on $\mathbb A^4$ by $t\cdot(x,y, z, w) = (tx,t^{-1}y,tz,t^{-1}w)$, and let $f\colon \mathbb A^4 \to \mathbb A^1$ be defined by $f(x,y) = xy + zw$.

Comment: I had the exact same counterexample typed up and was about to submit! The only remaining value added was the statement "Degeneration can produce new fixed points."

Comment: To Allen: nice statement, though!

Comment: While this is an interesting example, it doesn't actually answer my question; the fiber at the origin doesn't have rational singularities, since its normalization is disconnected.

Comment: Dear Ben, I believe that the modified version above should satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I prefer to think of the map in the variant as $\det: M_{2\times 2} \to {\mathbb A}^1$. 